# Prevent keyboard from scrolling UITextField underneath headerview in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a tableview with a header and under that header I've a couple of UITextFields inside a UITableViewCell. The problem is that when I press the top UITextField, the UITextField scrolls underneath the headerView. How do I prevent this from happening? I've disabled scrolling in the tableview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to split up the UITableViewCell containing two UITextFields to two UITableViewCells (each containing a UITextField).